# To delete, Changing the flag of entity VS Moving to another table?

Tags: sql, delete-row

Should I change the column `deleted` to `1` to consider it as deleted or it is better to move the record to another table?

The flag approach is good because later selects will search less records.
The second approach is a little complex, isn't it?

Which approach is better?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: MySQL (InnoDB).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated [here](http://abstraction.blog/2015/06/28/soft-vs-hard-delete) **Comparison Factors** are listed below. It is up-to you take the decision based on below factor

***Ease of Setup***

- Soft Delete is easier to implement since it merely involves updating
  a column while hard delete would also involve copying the data to be
  deleted to an audit table.

> Advantage : Soft Delete

***Debugging***

- Soft Delete makes it easy to debug data issues due to the
  deleted_flag But debugging via the Audit table is also easily
  possible. So its a tie.

> Advantage : NA

***Restoring data***

- It is extremely easy to restore data ‘deleted’ via soft delete since
  it just involved unsetting the deleted_flag.
- However note that restoring data is an extremely rare occurance.

> Advantage : Soft Delete

***Querying for active data***

- By experience, I can state that many issues have come up when the
  developer has forgotten to add ‘delete_flag = 0’ condition in the
  select queries due to which issues came about.
- If you are using an ORM like Doctrine with the ‘soft delete’ plugin
  enabled, then this will not be an issue since the ORM takes care of
  adding this check.

> Advantage : Hard Delete

***View Simplicity***

- Having all the data in the tables as active data relates to view
  simplicity (WYSIWYG - What you see is what you get)
- In Hard delete, all ‘deleted’ data will only be present in the audit
  table while the rest of the tables in the system will have ‘active’
  data. So the separation of concerns exists for hard delete.

> Advantage : Hard Delete

***Performance of operation***

- Update is a bit faster than delete (microseconds)
- So soft delete should technically be faster than hard delete (which
  also has the audit table insert to consider).

> Advantage : Soft Delete

***Application Performance***

- Speed

  - To support soft deletes, ALL select queries need to have a condition
    ‘WHERE delete_flag = 0’.
  - In situations where JOINs are involved there will be multiple such
    conditions. Select queries with lesser conditions are faster than
    those with conditions.

> Advantage : Hard Delete

- Size

  - To support faster soft deletes, we need to have an index for every
    delete_flag in EVERY table
  - Additionally the table size keeps increasing since the table has
    ‘soft deleted’ data + active data.
  - Queries can get slower as table size increases.

> Advantage : Hard Delete

***Database features compatibility***
**Unique Index**

- Unique index ensures data integrity by preventing multiple
  occurrences of a row at the database level.
- Having soft delete prevents usage of Unique index.
- Additionally we cannot update the old soft deleted entry of A1-B1
  since it would mean rewriting some data which results in loss of
  recorded data (eg : update date time or some other deleted_by column
  if it exists)

> Advantage : Hard Delete

***Cascading***

- For soft delete, we cannot make use of ‘ON DELETE’ cascading. The
  alternative is to create an ‘UPDATE’ trigger which keeps track of
  deleted_flag.

> Advantage : Hard Delete

Comment: Very thorough explanation :) Thanks